# Trozear cadena de texto en python

Tags: python

En un codigo en python estoy intentando trozear un texto de una ruta hacia un fichero.

```
/home/environment/path/attach/file.txt
```

La idea, que no se llevar a cabo. Es trozear venga lo que venga como cadena de texto y quedarme solamente con el contenido de la ultima / hasta el final. Es decir, file.txt.

Puede que en vez de tener cuatro niveles (home, environment, path, attach) tenga mas. Por lo que la idea es que se queda con todo lo que haya despues de la ultima barra vertical

Comment: Puedes utilizar el método `split` de `string`: `cadena.split('/')[-1]`, pero yo te recomendaría usar el método `split` del módulo `path`: `from os import path`, `path.split(cadena)[-1]` o directamente `path.basename(cadena)` el cual te da el nombre del fichero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque puedes utilizar métodos de cadenas como `split()`, `rsplit()` y similares, el método recomendado para procesar rutas de archivos es hacer uso de la librería `pathlib`, pues eso hace que sea más portable el código (que funcione para rutas de otros operativos, que pueden usar quizás otros separadores para carpetas, etc).

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("/home/environment/path/attach/file.txt").name
'file.txt'
```

Comment: Siempre un paso más allá. Desconocía el módulo pathlib. ¿Hay alguna diferencia con el módulo path?

Comment: `pathlib` replica muchas de las características que antes estaban en `os`  y en `os.path`, pero de una forma más estructurada, organizada y coherente. Una vez tienes un objeto de tipo `Path()`, que representa un nombre de fichero o carpeta, puedes hacer cosas como ver si existe, crearlo, borrarlo, tomar la ruta, tomar el nombre, etc. todo mediante métodos de ese objeto. Se supone que es la forma "moderna" de hacerlo (lee por ejemplo [Don’t Use Python OS Library Any More When Pathlib Can Do](https://towardsdatascience.com/dont-use-python-os-library-any-more-when-pathlib-can-do-141fefb6bdb5)

Comment: Interesante artículo! Entiendo que esto sirve para tener cohesionados todo esos métodos en un objeto, que al final es de lo que trata la POO. Muchas gracias por la explicación, siempre se aprende algo nuevo contigo! Crack!!

Comment: Genial respuesta y valida. Muchas gracias !!!